# JavaFX center text

Tags: javafx

I cannot figure out why, but the text on this is not centering on the screen no matter what I do, it is aligning on the left. please help.

```java
public class FarmApp extends Application {

    Scene scene;
    HBox pane;
    Stage gameStage;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        pane = new HBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1500, 900);
        createWelcome();

        this.scene = scene;
        gameStage = stage;

        stage.setTitle("Chuggville");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    } // start

    /**
     * Creates the welcome screen for Farm game
     */
    public void createWelcome() {



        HBox hbox2 = new HBox();
        Text chugville = new Text();
        chugville.setText("Chugville");
        chugville.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 90));
        BorderPane centerText2 = new BorderPane();
        centerText2.setCenter(chugville);

        hbox2.getChildren().addAll(centerText2);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(centerText2);
    }

}
```

Comment: work through a tutorial on layouts ..

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have so much noise in your code that it's hard to know what's causing the issue.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {        
        BorderPane welcomeScreen = createWelcome();
        Scene scene = new Scene(welcomeScreen, 1500, 900);
        stage.setTitle("Chuggville");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } // start

    /**
     * Creates the welcome screen for Farm game
     * @return 
     */
    public BorderPane createWelcome() {
        Text chugville = new Text();
        chugville.setText("Chugville");
        chugville.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 90));
        BorderPane centerText2 = new BorderPane();
        centerText2.setCenter(chugville);        

        return centerText2;
    }
}
```